# Explaining the disinvolutivity of a distribution in light of an integral submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Here is the problem 19-5 of Lee's *introduction to smooth manifolds*.

> Let $D$ be the distribution of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by
>   \begin{align*}
> X&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+yz\frac{\partial}{\partial z}, & Y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
> \end{align*}
>
> (a) Find an integral submanifold of $D$ passing through the origin.
>
> (b) Is $D$ involutive? Explain your answer in light of (a).

Clearly, the plane $\{(x,y,0):x,y \in \mathbb R \}$ is an integral submanifold of $D$ passing through the origin. My question is about how to prove that $D$ isn't involutive **in light of (a)**(By the way, I think part(b) is easy to figure out as a separate problem, since $[X,Y]=-z\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \in D \iff z=0$) 
In order to see (b) in light of (a), we notice that if $D$ is an involutive distribution, then it is completely integrable by Frobenius theorem, which means there is a smooth flat chart $(U,\varphi)=(U,x_1,x_2,x_3)$ around $O=(0,0,0)$ such that

(1) $\varphi(U)$ is a cube in $\mathbb R^3$;

(2) At points of $U$, $D$, as a two dimensional distribution, is spanned by the first two coordinate vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$,$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$.

I feel like there should be some contradiction aroused by (2). But I can't find a rigorous explanation.

If applying the Frobenius theorem is not professor Lee's purpose of giving this question, then how do we see (b) **in light of (a)** in an appropriate way?

Comment: One integral manifold does not get you a whole neighborhood's worth of integral manifolds.

Comment: @TedShifrin  I completely agree with you. I just don't know how to take advantage of part(a)

Comment: They just want you to realize what we've said, that (a) in no way implies involutivity.